# Finding certain plotting style

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am looking for a plotting function in matplotlib that plots the y-values as bars just like in an autocorrelogram but for a general function. Is there a method to do this in matplotlib or do I have to write my own function?

Comment: Do you have an example to show?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/xcorr_acorr_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-xcorr-acorr-demo-py it should look like this

Comment: Because your initial question is a little unclear, what about your use case is different enough that it doesn't allow you to use the sample code in the given example? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The example given computes the autocorrelation function and then plots it in that specific style. I, however, only want to have the same plotting style but do NOT want to compute the autocorrelation before. As I do not know how to do it I do not know what could be provided in a sample code.

Comment: That helped clarify your question, thank you. In this case, you will likely have to set all of the style elements individually, as there doesn't seem to be a preset [style sheet](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html) in matplotlib for that plot style

Comment: Thank you! I think I have found a work around now: I can use the errorbar function and define the upper and lower intervals accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`stem`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html)

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(21)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(5,75)
y = np.random.randn(len(x))

plt.stem(x,y, linefmt="k", markerfmt="none", basefmt="C0", use_line_collection=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]